# Openshift: How to increase the memory limit for sti-build

Tags: openshift

I'm using (the free trial of) Openshift online and this tier apparently offers 2G of memory for the pods.
I'm trying to install a node project and the npm install phase tries to build some native modules and terminates with an oom error, while trying a gcc compile.

On looking the console we can see that the sti-build container has a limit of 512M

```
Containers
sti-build
Image: openshift3/ose-docker-builder
Command: openshift-sti-build --loglevel=0
Mount: buildworkdir → /tmp/build read-write
Mount: docker-socket → /var/run/docker.sock read-write
Mount: crio-socket → /var/run/crio/crio.sock read-write
Mount: builder-dockercfg-kpj4q-push → /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/push read-only
Mount: builder-dockercfg-kpj4q-pull → /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/pull read-only
Mount: builder-token-pl672 → /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount read-only
CPU: 30 millicores to 1 core
Memory: 409 MiB to 512 MiB
```

This seems to come from a limit ranger that the platform has injected - as the documentation says that builds should be unlimited.

Any way of overriding?

Comment: Take a look at https://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-memory-a-build-can-use.html

Comment: Will's comment is very much on the right track. In case the cookbook link changes the main point is to patch the config `oc patch bc/cookbook --patch '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'`. I'm still not sure how to get this in a templated pipeline rather than a run twice manual process